# Différence entre « se trouver » et « être »

Tags: sens

Quelle est la différence entre « être » et « se trouver » ?

Exemple :

- Se trouver belle - être belle
- Se trouver à Paris - être à Paris

Peut-on m'expliquer quand est-ce que j'emploie « se trouver » ou « être » ?

J'utilise les deux pour décrire une situation.

Comment: On peut aussi utiliser les deux: *je me trouve être à peu près le seul homme, dans le monde, qui ne puisse plus le publier* Alexandre Dumas.

Comment: @jlliagre : J'adore! Les deux et même... plusieurs fois... : Allez zyva! à propos de AD donc: *Il est qu'il se trouve qu'il se trouve être à peu près le seul...* ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Les deux exemples se ressemblent, mais il y a une différence cachée.

Dans le premier exemple, on utilise le verbe "trouver" avec un pronom personnel.

```
Elle se trouve belle / Elle trouve qu'elle est belle. (C'est son opinion.)

Je la trouve belle / Je trouve qu'elle est belle. (C'est mon opinion.)

Elle est belle. (C'est un jugement ou un fait.)
```

Dans ce cas, on ne peut pas substituer "trouver" et "être" sans changer le sens de la phrase (trouver <= opinion, être <= fait/jugement).

Dans le second cas, il s'agit du verbe pronominal "se trouver"

```
Elle se trouve à Paris. (C'est un fait.)

Je me trouve à Paris. (C'est un fait.)

Elle est à Paris. (C'est un fait.)
```

Dans ce cas (localisation), "être" et "se trouver" peuvent être intervertis sans changer le sens de la phrase, même si "se trouver" apporte une petite nuance et, surtout, fait plus "littéraire".

Comment: Petit bémol : Je remplacerais bien dans ton opposition (trouver <= opinion, être <= fait) *fait* par : **jugement**. X est Y est la forme la plus élémentaire d'un jugement. Pas d'un fait.

Comment: merci pour la remarque. J'ai modifié ma réponse mais j'ai laissé le fait car ce n'est pas toujours un jugement non plus.  Pour moi, il y a une différence entre "elle est belle" et "elle se juge belle".

Comment: +1 car... tu es gentil! et... que je serais trop stupide de balancer dans le HS pour une bricole... ;-)

Comment: « Être » ne peut pas servir à exprimer un jugement ; tout inférence qu'une assertion n'a qu'une valeur de jugement, provient soit d'une déclaration à cet effet (Je juge que… Nous pensons que …,etc.) soit d'une révélation indépendante de cette affirmation que l'état proclamé n'est pas vérifié, et de la conclusion que le locuteur qui a affirmé l'existence de cet état ne l'a pas fait en connaissance de cause, en d'autre termes, qu'il s'est plus ou moins trompé. Si on vous demande « Est-ce que vous pensez qu'elle est belle ? » et que vous répondez « Elle est belle. » on n'est pas très (1/3)

Comment: sûr de ce que vous dites et on peut légitimement vous dire « Je ne vous demande pas ce qu'elle est selon les standards reconnus, mais ce que vous pensez. ». Prenons le cas de base qui ne repose pas sur un consensus difficile à déterminer : «  — La porte était-elle ouverte ? — Elle était ouverte. » ; il n'y a aucune possibilité d'interpréter cela comme un jugement. Que le consensus émane d'une seule personne et soit sans problème ou qu'il émane d'un groupe très étendu et difficile à déterminer, la question reste la même : (2/3)

Comment: toute affirmation repose sur un consensus, est l'expression des conclusions que ce consensus a produites. (3/3)

Comment: @LPH : Vous êtes chiant!

Comment: @radouxju : Et moi je suis un misérable! Pardon radouxju d'avoir foutu le souk.

Comment: @aCOSwt Holà ! Trop de chianti !

Answer (score -1):

**I**

Il y a trois types de situation dans lesquelles ces deux verbes sont utilisés.

**a**) Dans le premier il s'agit seulement d'affirmer que quelqu'un ou quelque chose, à un moment donné, occupe une certaine location, un point donné. Lorsqu'il s'agit de cet usage les deux verbes sont presque synonymes. Dans cet usage « être » est plus fréquemment utilisé ([ngram1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=se+trouve+en+Afrique%2Cest+en+Afrique&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cse%20trouve%20en%20Afrique%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cest%20en%20Afrique%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cse%20trouve%20en%20Afrique%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cest%20en%20Afrique%3B%2Cc0), [ngram2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=est+sur+la+table%2Cse+trouve+sur+la+table&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cest%20sur%20la%20table%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cse%20trouve%20sur%20la%20table%3B%2Cc0)) parce que c'est un verbe qui n'exprime pas de nuances. Au contraire, « se trouver » exprime la nuance d'« être placé soudainement ou par un effet du hasard en tel lieu » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trouver)), mais pas toujours, comme cette nuance est parfois absente et que le verbe est alors synonyme de « être ».

- L'équipe était à Paris la semaine dernière. • L'équipe se trouvait à Paris la semaine dernière.
- Il est dans sa chambre. • Il se trouve dans sa chambre.
- Le livre est sur la table. • Le livre se trouve sur la table.
- L'Égypte se trouve/est dans le nord-est de l'Afrique. (*pas de nuance*)

**b)** Dans le second type, il s'agit d'affirmer que quelqu'un est sujet à un état donné et le même principe que pour les positions est vrai sauf que les  nuances attachées au verbe « se trouver » sont toujours effectives (être à un moment donné dans tel état, telle situation, telle position » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trouver)).

- L'instituteur **se trouvait** *malade* ce jour-là et un remplaçant s'occupa de la classe. (*L'état est celui d'être malade.*)
- La commission d'enquête **se trouve** dans *l'impossibilité de conclure*. (*L'état est celui d'être dans l'impossibilité de conclure.*)

Dans les deux exemples précédents « être » peut aussi être utilisé mais la notion de hasard n'existe plus.

**c**) Dans le troisième, « être » sert à formuler la vérité absolue d'un état, c'est à dire un fait, quelque chose dont la vérification ne dépend pas de l'opinion, des perceptions ou des sentiments de quelqu'un ou d'un groupe particulier de personnes. « Se trouver » sert à  formuler une opinion ou un sentiment qu'il existe un état de chose donné mais qu'il existe, fondamentalement, d'après un point de vue personnel ; cela signifie que ce qui est affirmé peut ne pas être vrai.

- Elle **se trouve** très malade mais en réalité elle n'**est** pas malade, elle a seulement un mal de tête passager. (*Elle croit, elle pense être malade mais elle ne l'est pas.*)
- Jean **se trouve** mal préparé pour la compétition mais son entraineur dit qu'il **est** très bien préparé.
- Elle **se trouve** belle et en effet tout le monde dit qu'elle **est** belle.

**II**

Il existe un emploi impersonnel de « se trouver » qu'il ne faut pas confondre. Dans l'emploi impersonnel le sujet est toujours « il » et ce pronom ne représente personne ; c'est le même pronom que l'on utilise dans des phrase comme « Il pleut. » et « Il fait soleil. ». Le verbe a alors deux significations essentielles.

1/ *Il existe, il y a* (encore deux tournures impersonnelles)

- Il se trouve de nombreuse espèces de poisson dans cette rivière.

2/ *Il arrive*

- Il se trouve parfois  que les poissons ne mordent pas de toute la journée.